# Excel: filter table rows by specified column value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, ms-query

I have a table with first column as primary key. Ex:

```
id  value1  value2
1       10      5
2       2       3
3       12      5
..
```

I also have a second list of id's I want to select, which can have repeated ids. Ex:

```
selectId
1
2
2
2
5
10
..
```

How can I "merge" the two tables (something like INNER JOIN) to obtain:

```
id  value1  value2
1       10      5
2       2       3
2       2       3
2       2       3
5       99      99
10      22      22
..
```

I tried using 'Microsoft Query' from Data > Extern Data  to join the two tables. The problem is that it seems it cannot handle tables with more than 256 columns.

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Thanks, `VLOOKUP` works as intended.
However one problem is that if the row was found but that corresponding column was blank, this function returns `0` (where I expected it to return an `empty cell`), and since zero is a valid value, I have no way to differentiate between the two (blank and zero)?
Any help is appreciated..

Comment: where is your database? is it Access, SQL Server OR Oracle? What query have you written that throws this error? Does your table have 256 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the **VLOOKUP** function would get you the data in the layout you require.

If you are using Tables in Excel 2007, the formula would look like this based on the example below.

```
in cell B8 
=VLOOKUP([selectId],Table1,2,FALSE)

in cell C8
=VLOOKUP([selectId],Table1,3,FALSE)
```

[Lookup screenshot http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/1/lookupz.png](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/1/lookupz.png)

Answer (score 3):

If this is Excel -like the title says- just use vlookups.
Not very relational, but that's the Excel way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where you store your data, but it looks like you have this problem, described on Microsoft site:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272729

Comment: Like I said, I already have the excel files with multiple sheets, with one table per sheet. I rather trying to select a subset of rows from one table determined by the key column of that table, where the desired keys are stored in a second table.

Comment: The restriction of 256 cols was when I tried to use MS-Query to merge the tables and return the result...