# How to check if two rows are identical and contain the same data in a list of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of lines in the D column and every line has a few properties in columns I, J, K and so on. I want to check my list if any rows contain the same properties and same line number. I want to delete the identical row and all the information in the columns. I'm new to VB so have no idea where to begin. My Sheet is called "Sheet1" and the column begins at D30 and goes to the right up until column AK30. The row begins at 30 and goes down to 7000. If anyone could help me with this it would much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the position of the properties in your column important? Would each of 6970 cells contained in a column have a different value (if not blank)? Would it be possible to sort the columns using excel's sort function (not vba's)?

Comment: Each line number has to correspond with the properties that are in the same row as the line number. There are some who have no line number but still have properties. All i want is to delete the lines with the same properties and identical line number. There are many identical line numbers but they all have different properties. no two lines should have the same properties. The sort function wont work.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is use something very similiar to the used in 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289461/excel-matching-values-in-cells-a-and-b-with-same-values-when-found-in-cells-c-an):

- Add a new column where you **"Concatenate"** all the paremeters to be checked in the row.
- Seleect all your data and **"Remove Duplicates"** that appear based in the column with concatenated results.

**concatenate** is a formula to string together the input values, where **Remove Duplicates** is self explanatory and is under **Data** tab in the **Data Tools** subtab (in excel 2007).

Regards